# Python multi-loop failed when with generator and iterator

Tags: python, loops, iterator, generator

I need a 2D loop of which the first loop uses an iterator and the second uses a generator, but this simple function failed to work, can anyone help to check?

```
def alphabet(begin, end):
    for number in xrange(ord(begin), ord(end)+1):
        yield chr(number)

def test(a, b):
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            print i, j

test(xrange(8, 10), alphabet('A', 'C'))

The result shows:
>>> 8 A
>>> 8 B
>>> 8 c
```

don't know why? thanks in advance if any one can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've asked for clarification, I'll say a bit more; but really [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290961/577088)'s answer sums it up pretty well: you can only iterate over a generator once. The code in your example tries to iterate over it three times, once for each value in `a`.

To see what I mean, consider this simplistic example:

```
>>> def mygen(x):
...     i = 0
...     while i < x:
...         yield i
...         i += 1
... 
>>> mg = mygen(4)
>>> list(mg)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> list(mg)
[]
```

When `mygen` is called, it creates an object which can be iterated over exactly once. When you try to iterate over it again, you get an empty iterable.

This means you have to call `mygen` anew, *every* time you want to iterate over it`. So in other words (using a rather verbose style)...

```
>>> def make_n_lists(gen, gen_args, n):
...     list_of_lists = []
...     for _ in range(n):
...         list_of_lists.append(list(gen(*gen_args)))
...     return list_of_lists
... 
>>> make_n_lists(mygen, (3,), 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

If you wanted to bind your arguments to your generator and pass that as an argumentless function, you could do this (using a more terse style):

```
>>> def make_n_lists(gen_func, n):
...     return [list(gen_func()) for _ in range(n)]
... 
>>> make_n_lists(lambda: mygen(3), 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

The `lambda` just defines an anonymous function; the above is identical to this:

```
>>> def call_mygen_with_3():
...     return mygen(3)
... 
>>> make_n_lists(call_mygen_with_3, 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, your post is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The first iteration over `b` consumes the generator.

Comment: Sorry, but could you be more specific?